# Best way to export ggplot2 graphs to a Word document?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created some awesome graphs that I want to export to my Word document. Yea, should write in Markdown but... you know... someday!

However, how do I resize the graphs to the right dimensions while labels stay "within" the perimeter? See the following examples (code is at the end of the document).

I want to insert the following graph into my word document:

[image: Test picture]

Looks great! Not when I insert it into the document:

[image: Word screenshot]

Labels are two tiny, and I would love to stretch it vertically, so the width is greater than the height. So I managed to produce this:

[image]

And this is were I am stuck. How do I keep the labels within the perimeters? And is there a better way to "fit" the word document than guessing correct dimensions?

Thanks!

This is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- mpg # Load sample data

# First test graph 
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(cyl, hwy)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = "This is just one very long label to prove a point ..... 1234",
       x = "Cyl") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())

ggsave("test1.png")

# Modified test graph to add fit the Word document

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(cyl, hwy)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = "This is just one very long label to prove a point ..... 1234",
       x = "Cyl") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 12) + # SIZE CHANGED
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())

ggsave("test2.png", width = 8, height = 4) # DIMENSIONS DEFINED
```

Comment: Hi, did you see officer package .. ?

Answer (score 1):

A solution I tend to use involves the `officer` package as mentioned above. This *used to* be able export graphs as vector objects to docx so you could change sizes and text in the graph when it's in the document. This seems to have been suspended in recent versions, but still works for powerpoint. The following code puts the graph as a grouped shape in a powerpoint slide where you can tweak it before copying into word:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)
library(tidyverse)

df <- mpg # Load sample data

# First test graph 
plot2 <- ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(cyl, hwy)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = "This is just one very long label to prove a point ..... 1234",
       x = "Cyl") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 12) + # SIZE CHANGED
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())

pptx <- read_pptx()

pptx %>% 
  add_slide() %>% 
  # This first line puts it in as a static png image for comparison
  ph_with(plot2, location = ph_location_type(type = "body")) %>% 
  add_slide() %>% 
  # This line puts in a shape object, which can be ungrouped and edited
  ph_with(rvg::dml(ggobj = plot2),
          width = 8,
          height = 4, 
          location = ph_location_type(type = "body"))

#> pptx document with 2 slide(s)

print(pptx, "test_graph.pptx")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

That's a sort of tweaky solution which at least allows you visual control over sizes. This used to be more easily provided through the `export` package ([available on GitHub](https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export)), but it's not on CRAN anymore and behind the scenes used the now defunct parts of `officer` to put vector graphics in docx documents.

---

Edit: [See this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/davidgohel/rvg/issues/36) for an explanation of why vector graphics to docx is no longer an option through `officer`.